# Parent child JSON from CSV using Python sunburst

Tags: python, json, csv, d3.js, parent-child

I would like to create a hierarchy name child JSON for sunburst. Using python I created a code but the column of totalyearlycompensation needs to show sum where all other 4 columns are same. For example

```
Product Manager,Master's Degree,Asian,Male,4500000
Product Manager,Master's Degree,Asian,Male,4980000
```

this should reflect total totalyearlycompensation as (9480000)

```
title,Education,Race,gender,totalyearlycompensation
Mechanical Engineer,Bachelor's Degree,Asian,Male,5000
Mechanical Engineer,Bachelor's Degree,Asian,Male,5000
Mechanical Engineer,Bachelor's Degree,Asian,Female,180000
Data Scientist,Bachelor's Degree,Asian,Female,180000
Software Engineer,Bachelor's Degree,Asian,Male,10000
Software Engineer,Bachelor's Degree,Asian,Male,10000
Sales,Master's Degree,Asian,Male,10000
Software Engineer,Master's Degree,Asian,Male,10000
Software Engineer,Bachelor's Degree,Asian,Male,10000
Software Engineer,Bachelor's Degree,Asian,Male,10000
Software Engineer,Bachelor's Degree,Asian,Male,10000
Software Engineer,Bachelor's Degree,Asian,Female,10000
Software Engineer,Bachelor's Degree,Asian,Male,11000
Business Analyst,Master's Degree,Asian,Male,11000
Software Engineer,Bachelor's Degree,Asian,Male,11000
Software Engineer,Master's Degree,Asian,Male,11000
Software Engineer,Bachelor's Degree,Asian,Male,11000
Software Engineer,Bachelor's Degree,Asian,Male,11000
Software Engineer,Bachelor's Degree,Asian,Male,11000
Software Engineer,Bachelor's Degree,Asian,Male,11000
Software Engineer,Bachelor's Degree,Asian,Female,11000
Software Engineer,Bachelor's Degree,Asian,Male,11000
Software Engineer,Bachelor's Degree,Asian,Male,11000
Human Resources,Master's Degree,Asian,Female,11000
Product Designer,Bachelor's Degree,Asian,Male,13000
Software Engineer,Bachelor's Degree,Asian,Male,13000
Software Engineering Manager,Bachelor's Degree,Asian,Male,13000
Software Engineering Manager,Master's Degree,White,Female,1605000
Software Engineering Manager,Bachelor's Degree,White,Male,1733000
Software Engineering Manager,Master's Degree,Black,Male,2372000
Product Manager,Master's Degree,Asian,Male,4500000
Product Manager,Master's Degree,Asian,Male,4980000
...........................................continues with more similar data **
```

Output similar to this

```
{
    "name": "Flare",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Mechanical Engineer",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": Bachelor's Degree",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Asian",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "Male",
                                    "totalyearlycompensation": 10000
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Female",
                                    "totalyearlycompensation": 180000
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "White",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "Male",
                                    "totalyearlycompensation": 550000
                                },
                               
                               
                            ]
                        },
                       
                    ]
                },
                
                {
                    "name": "Master's Degree",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Asian",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "Male",
                                    "totalyearlycompensation": 222000
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

My code

```
import csv
import json
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, size=None):
        self.name = name
        self.children = []
        self.size = size

    def child(self, cname, size=None):
        child_found = [c for c in self.children if c.name == cname]
        if not child_found:
            _child = Node(cname, size)
            self.children.append(_child)
        else:
            _child = child_found[0]
        return _child

    def as_dict(self):
        res = {'name': self.name}
        if self.size is None:
            res['children'] = [c.as_dict() for c in self.children]
        else:
            res['size'] = self.size
        return res
root = Node('Flare')

with open('DataLevels.csv', 'r') as f:
      reader = csv.reader(f)
      next(reader)
      for row in reader:
        grp1, grp2, grp3, grp4, size = row
        root.child(grp1).child(grp2).child(grp3).child(grp4, int(size))

print (json.dumps(root.as_dict(), indent=5))
 with open('output.json', 'w') as f2:
    (json.dump(root.as_dict(), f2, indent=4,ensure_ascii=False))
```

Comment: This information should be in a database.  Then, you can use a simple SQL aggregation query (`SELECT title,education,race,sum(totalyearlycompensation) FROM table GROUP BY title,educaiton,race;`).

Comment: And, just for terminology's sake, this is not a "parent child" relationship.  This is just grouping.

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks for the quick reply, but the parent child relationship is at the bottom of the question after the csv.

Comment: Ah, that was not present in the question when I looked at it.  Wouldn't you want to know the AVERAGE compensation, or at least the number of entries?  The total compensation is not a useful metric by itself.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes Average compensation would be great but I am in need of sum for yearlycompensation for a sunburst.

Answer (score 0):

The data is more naturally stored as a dictionary, with the names as the keys, instead of as a list.  I think this does what you want.  Note that `Node` is now essentially a fancy `defaultdict` that creates all its children as `defaultdict`s.

```
import csv
import json

class Node:
    def __init__(self, name, size=0):
        self.name = name
        self.size = size
        self.children = {}

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if idx not in self.children:
            self.children[idx] = Node(idx)
        return self.children[idx]

    def as_dict(self):
        res = { "name": self.name }
        if self.size:
            res["sum"] =  self.size
        else:
            res["children"] = [v.as_dict() for v in self.children.values()]
        return res

root = Node('Flare')

with open('x.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        grp1, grp2, grp3, grp4, size = row
        root[grp1][grp2][grp3][grp4].size += int(size)

print (json.dumps(root.as_dict(), indent=5))
with open('output.json', 'w') as f2:
    (json.dump(root.as_dict(), f2, indent=4,ensure_ascii=False))
```

Output:

```
{
     "name": "Flare",
     "children": [
          {
               "name": "Mechanical Engineer",
               "children": [
                    {
                         "name": "Bachelor's Degree",
                         "children": [
                              {
                                   "name": "Asian",
                                   "children": [
                                        {
                                             "name": "Male",
                                             "sum": 10000
                                        },
                                        {
                                             "name": "Female",
                                             "sum": 180000
                                        }
                                   ]
                              }
                         ]
                    }
               ]
          },
          {
               "name": "Data Scientist",
               "children": [
                    {
                         "name": "Bachelor's Degree",
                         "children": [
                              {
                                   "name": "Asian",
                                   "children": [
                                        {
                                             "name": "Female",
                                             "sum": 180000
                                        }
                                   ]
                              }
                         ]
                    }
               ]
          },
          {
               "name": "Software Engineer",
               "children": [
                    {
                         "name": "Bachelor's Degree",
                         "children": [
                              {
                                   "name": "Asian",
                                   "children": [
                                        {
                                             "name": "Male",
                                             "sum": 151000
                                        },
                                        {
                                             "name": "Female",
                                             "sum": 21000
                                        }
                                   ]
                              }
                         ]
                    },
                    {
                         "name": "Master's Degree",
                         "children": [
                              {
                                   "name": "Asian",
                                   "children": [
                                        {
                                             "name": "Male",
                                             "sum": 21000
                                        }
                                   ]
                              }
                         ]
                    }
               ]
          },
          {
               "name": "Sales",
               "children": [
                    {
                         "name": "Master's Degree",
                         "children": [
                              {
                                   "name": "Asian",
                                   "children": [
                                        {
                                             "name": "Male",
                                             "sum": 10000
                                        }
                                   ]
                              }
                         ]
                    }
               ]
          },
          {
               "name": "Business Analyst",
               "children": [
                    {
                         "name": "Master's Degree",
                         "children": [
                              {
                                   "name": "Asian",
                                   "children": [
                                        {
                                             "name": "Male",
                                             "sum": 11000
                                        }
                                   ]
                              }
                         ]
                    }
               ]
          },
          {
               "name": "Human Resources",
               "children": [
                    {
                         "name": "Master's Degree",
                         "children": [
                              {
                                   "name": "Asian",
                                   "children": [
                                        {
                                             "name": "Female",
                                             "sum": 11000
                                        }
                                   ]
                              }
                         ]
                    }
               ]
          },
          {
               "name": "Product Designer",
               "children": [
                    {
                         "name": "Bachelor's Degree",
                         "children": [
                              {
                                   "name": "Asian",
                                   "children": [
                                        {
                                             "name": "Male",
                                             "sum": 13000
                                        }
                                   ]
                              }
                         ]
                    }
               ]
          },
          {
               "name": "Software Engineering Manager",
               "children": [
                    {
                         "name": "Bachelor's Degree",
                         "children": [
                              {
                                   "name": "Asian",
                                   "children": [
                                        {
                                             "name": "Male",
                                             "sum": 13000
                                        }
                                   ]
                              },
                              {
                                   "name": "White",
                                   "children": [
                                        {
                                             "name": "Male",
                                             "sum": 1733000
                                        }
                                   ]
                              }
                         ]
                    },
                    {
                         "name": "Master's Degree",
                         "children": [
                              {
                                   "name": "White",
                                   "children": [
                                        {
                                             "name": "Female",
                                             "sum": 1605000
                                        }
                                   ]
                              },
                              {
                                   "name": "Black",
                                   "children": [
                                        {
                                             "name": "Male",
                                             "sum": 2372000
                                        }
                                   ]
                              }
                         ]
                    }
               ]
          },
          {
               "name": "Product Manager",
               "children": [
                    {
                         "name": "Master's Degree",
                         "children": [
                              {
                                   "name": "Asian",
                                   "children": [
                                        {
                                             "name": "Male",
                                             "sum": 9480000
                                        }
                                   ]
                              }
                         ]
                    }
               ]
          }
     ]
}
```